# ProgressDialog not showing while uploading images into server with StrictMode.ThreadPolicy

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

`ProgressDialog` is showing only if I am sending text but when I sent images it gave me an error which tells that there are lot of activities running or the app can't handle all of it, the solution is to add  `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` before invoking those tasks but the problem is `ProgressDialog` is not showing anymore which is important to tell the user about the ongoing process.

I believe it is `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` that causes the `ProgressDialog` to disappear. I am not using `Asynctask` that's why I haven't found solution on the Internet yet because most of them are using it. I am also planning to use `Asynctask` but my boss did not approve it, he's afraid that it will ruin the app.

{

```
     private void upLoadImage(String path){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().penaltyDialog().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    uploadMedia(path);}}
```

{

```
    private void uploadMedia(String path) {
    String ImageName = "image_name";
    String ImagePath = "image_path";

  try {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    File uploadFile1 = new File(path);
    String requestURL= "http://myurl";
    MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL,   

 charset);
 multipart.addFormField(ImageName, "iName");
 multipart.addFormField(ImagePath, "iPath");
 multipart.addFilePart("uploadedfile", uploadFile1);
 List<String> response = multipart.finish();
  Log.v("rht", "SERVER REPLIED:");
 for (String line : response) {
      Log.v("rht", "Line : "+line);
       if(line=="true"||line=="Saved"){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
   }

       // Toast.makeText(this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: can you post the code??

Comment: I just posted my code.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you access Network  in UI thread the error is shown.You cannot do the network operations in the main thread.It is better to use a worker thread or ayntask. But if you are willing to accept the consequences, and must do network operations on the main thread, you can override the default behavior:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: does it mean using StrictMode.ThreadPolicy will cancel all UI operations?

Comment: No it wont..This line allows you to make network calls in the UI thread itself which gets your job done.But making Network call in UI thread is not good and can cause problems.

Comment: since my boss saw your comments he let me now do the Asynctask and it works fine. I was just assuming that there were some sort of chance or options to perform the task without using Asynctask. and I don't really expect to have negative on my question . Thank you anyway

Comment: creating an asyntask or a simple thread-handler will also work..Anyways if I helped you please upvote this answer

Comment: I got 3 down votes ..what is wrong with my question anyway?I just want to know so that I could make it right next time..